# Insufficient disk space to repair master file table

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, chkdsk

After I had to unplug my external HDD during copying on ubuntu, it became unreadable. I'd had this problem before and it can be fixed through chkdsk. But this time chkdsk failed with the following error:

```
Insufficient disk space to repair master file table
```

I DO NOT want to format my HDD and increasing the partition's size with gparted doesn't work as it requires chkdsk first.

Is there a way to fix this problem?
Is it possible to copy the entire partition using for example `dd` although it is unreadable on linux? (In that case maybe I could buy a new one and save the data)

Thank you

Comment: The partition is corrupted, so a `dd` copy will be corrupted to.

Comment: But will a dd copy on a larger hard drive leave enough space for the chkdsk?

Comment: No, because the partition size would be the same and attempting to resize it will further corrupt it.